# Laravel app with one or multiple Vue instances

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Disclaimer: this is not entirely a programming question, i am asking for your opinions. In case this post does not belong here, please let me know and I will remove it.

I am on the process of planning a rather big app using Laravel and VueJS. My main question is what is the best way to do it?

The app will involve users registrations, login, different user roles and permissions, profile pages etc.

Is it a good idea to use Laravel router to load the pages and create multiple Vue instances for each page? i.e. have one Vue instance handle the frontpage, have another Vue instance handle the profile page etc?

Or is it better to create one Vue instance with multiple components and use Laravel purely as API server?

Do you have any tutorials or resources that might help me decide on one approach or the other?

I would appreciate if you give me your view on this.

Thank you for reading :)

=====
Update

Thanks for your replies and time you spend on this. I got another question. Lets say I decided to go with MPA and I have 1 Vue app to handle one page, is it possible to use Vue router for each page? for example
'/profile page will be rendered by laravel 
Everything after /profile should be handled by Vue'

Now if I want VueJS to handle routing I put this in web.php

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('vueentrypoint');
})->where('any', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

Can I do something like

```
Route::get('/profile/{any?}', function () {
    return view('profileentry');
})->where('any', '[\/\w\.-]*');

Route::get('/user/{any?}', function () {
    return view('userentry');
})->where('any', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

Comment: It is certainly better to create one Vue app with multiple components and you can do this with the built in vue.js that ships with laravel by using the vue router and telling laravel to inherit the vue router configs.

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/using-vue-router-laravel

Comment: Thank you kyle, I will read the link as well :)

Comment: You're basically asking if you should build a Vue SPA or an MPA (multi-page app) with Laravel serving the views.  There is no correct answer here, it depends on your project requirements.  There are successful implementations of both..

Comment: *"...answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*

Comment: Hi to all and thank you for replies, I have update my first question with an additional question :)

Comment: I cant say that i know if that will work or not but from a development perspective it seems like overkill and, with respect, doesn't seem like you fully understand the concept of developing components inside a single page application.

Comment: Hi Kyle, you may be correct that is why am asking ;) this is the first time am trying to use vuejs in big project. My thinking is not to create a SPA app but to create multiple SPAs for each page, where its necessary of course. So one SPA may handle the frontpage and another one the profile page, each page might have multiple components. The in the profile i might want to allow the use to edit his profile so i will need vue router to show the editing form. I hope this makes clear of how am thinking, which might be totally wrong. :) And this is why am asking for opinions.

Answer (score 2):

If you need multiple in an Laravel instance, you should separate applications with more than one Vue instances. For example you have a e-commerce web application and you have three area and them is;

- Customer Dashboard: Customer information, wish lists, delivery information, bought items, help tickets etc.
- E-Commerce Website: Home page, Categories, Lists, Item Reviews and Buy Items
- Worker Dashboard: System updates, new items, new categories, new lists, help ticket views etc.

Note: Maybe Customer Dashboard and E-Commerce applications can be one but I love to separate customer dashboard from everything.

That three applications can separate with three Vue instances. And it is not best practice to make new Vue instances for just one page.

```
Route::get('/w/{any?}', 'SpaController@worker')->where('any', '.*')->name('spa.worker');
Route::get('/c/{any?}', 'SpaController@customer')->where('any', '.*')->name('spa.customer');
Route::get('{any}', 'SpaController@website')->where('any', '.*')->name('spa.website');
```

Comment: Hi @Mahodroid, Can you please share the implementation or code of spa.worker and spa.customer files?

Comment: that names are just titles of routes and they are routes to SpaController methods. 
That methods returns main blade views which has specific vue instances.

`public function worker() {
    return view('worker.app');
}`